# Как включить показ clip animation через animator при нажатии Onclick?

Tags: анимация, unity3d

Я из blender-a экспортировал .fbx с анимацией-clip. Как сделать, чтобы действие начиналось при нажатии кнопки?

```
 public GameObject youranimatableObject;
 private Animator yourAnimator;

 void Start()
 {
     yourAnimator = youranimatableObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
 }

 void Update()
 {
     if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
     {
             yourAnimator.animation.Play("slash"); // error 
             /*'Component.animation' is obsolete: 
             'Property animation has been deprecated. 
             Use GetComponent<Animation>() instead.  
             //but using it is not a solving)*/

     }

 }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у вас в контроллер "hand" добавлена анимация "slash" ?

Answer (score 1):

Изучите Animator. Это целая наука.
http://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/animation